# Can we set the permission of accessible to a branch only in a Git repository?

Tags: git, version-control, permissions, authorization, git-branch

We want to share a particular branch to our partner. Say we have a project on the Git repository, and it has a `master`, `develop` and several `feature/*` branches.

Now, we branch a `feature/prepare_shared_code` branch from the `develop` branch and remove some proprietary codes. And branch a `feature/work_phase_I` branch from the `feature/prepare_shared_code` branch.

Could we set the permission to a particular user that it can only access to this `feature/work_phase_I` branch? That is, the user can only view(log), read(clone), write(push) and create(branch) from this branch. It can not view the `develop`, `master`, `feature/prepare_shared_code` or other feature branches, so that it can not get the proprietary part of the source code.

We simply used the **Apache+Git** solution on a Windows server which is not easy to setup the permission for the git user. However, we have tried to move onto the [GitBlit](http://gitblit.com/) which might be the most powerful Java-stack Git server on Windows OS. Although it can manage the permission of the user but only for per repository and also some branch protection, such as review check before merging and not allowed to force push.

Comment: If you create a branch and just remove some code, that stuff is still available by following the prior history, regardless of which branch you're in. To properly hide that you would need to actually remove it from the history too, which is a different matter.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for the reply. We couldn't actually remove those codes from the history but only can temporarily remove it from particular branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: No, you can't directly give a user access to a branch while also preventing them from viewing the entire history of the branch.

## Why?

Each Git commit contains a pointer to the previous commit. Thus, if your history looks something like this:

```
* ffffff [feature/prepare_shared_code] some private commit
| * eeeeee [feature/work_phase_I] some public commit
| * dddddd some public commit
|/
* cccccc remove credentials
* bbbbbb some private commit
* aaaaaa some private commit
```

then by giving a user access to `feature/work_phase_I`, you are not only giving them access to commit `eeeeee` and `dddddd`, but also commits `aaaaaa`, `bbbbbb`, and `cccccc` (as well as any parents of `aaaaaa`).

This isn't something that can be fixed server-side without rewriting history, because the previous commit is included in the data used to generate the commit hash. (In theory, some web service could hide specific commits from specific users, but I assume this isn't what you are asking.)

## Workarounds

There are two possible workarounds here.

The first is the better long-term option: reorganize your codebase so that your proprietary code isn't mixed in with your more public code. Depending on your technology stack and your definition of "proprietary codes", this could mean creating libraries / packages, moving credentials to `.gitignore`d config files, moving code to submodules, etc.

The second option can be done without reorganizing your codebase. You can use an orphan branch and squash merges to maintain a separate history with none of the proprietary code.

Create a orphan branch:

```
git checkout --orphan partner_code some_public_branch
git commit -m "Initial public commit"
```

Then whenever you want to update the branch with new changes, do:

```
git checkout partner_code
git merge --squash feature/work_phase_I
```

The `--squash` flag will prevent the entire history of `feature/work_phase_I` from being included in `partner_code`.

## Re-integrating changes

You don't mention in your question whether there will be changes on the partner branch will need to be merged in to the mainline branch, but since you mention feature branches, I assume that is the case.

In my testing, doing a normal `git merge` from the orphan branch back to your private branch can cause extraneous merge conflicts. I found two workarounds for this.

### Cherry-pick

If there are only a few commits, you can just `git cherry-pick` each commit from the orphan branch to your private branch.

### Rebase

If there is a large number of commits on the orphan branch, you can use a temporary branch and `git rebase` to automate the process.

```
git checkout -b temp partner_code
git rebase --onto feature/work_phase_I abcdef12 temp
```

Where `abcdef12` is the last commit on the `partner_code` branch *before* the commits you need.

This will copy any new commits on the `partner_code` branch to a branch called `temp` that is based off `feature/work_phase_I`, so you can now merge that with your private branches as needed.

## Server-side support

My answer focused on how to create a branch that doesn't contain any of the proprietary code in the history. Once you have done this, it should be simple to limit a user's access to just that branch on the server-side using e.g. [Gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/). A Gitolite rule for this setup might look like this:

```
repo myrepo
  RW+              = @devs
  RW partner_code$ = @partners
```

This will allow anyone in the `devs` group to have full access, and anyone in the `partners` group to have read and (fast-forward) write access to the `partner_code` branch.

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for the answer and the workaround suggestion. I have tried to create the orphan branch which is actually a branch without any parent and history. There will be lots of change on our partner branch, so I thought it might be a little bit difficult to merge the branch back.

Comment: Besides, even I have created the orphan branch, we still need the git server(Gitolite or GitBlit) to have the permission setting of each branch. Otherwise, the partner user still can access to our private develop and/or master branch.

Comment: I had taken a look at the Gitolite document. It seems that Gitolite can set the permission of each branch in a repository as this link describe http://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf.html#rules

Comment: However, I still working on the Gitolite installation. Not quite sure that the - (the minus sign), to deny access is deny for all(including view, clone, push, delete) or just deny the RWD only, and the user still can view the history by git log.

Comment: I added an example of what the Gitolite config might look like. Does that help?

Comment: @Bruce I also did some testing and updated my answer with a better way to get changes from the orphan branch to a private branch.

Comment: Thanks for the rebase way. May I ask if we have a feature/partner which is branch from feature/prepare_code. And we give the permission setting in Gitolite as "RW+ feature/partner = @partners" and "- feature/prepare_code = @partners", which is allow partners group to have read, write, and create permission of feature/partner but deny all access to feature/prepare_code.

Comment: What will happen when @partners to access the feature/prepare_code? Is git clone will still let them read the feature/prepare_code branch? Could they checkout to the feature/prepare_code branch?

Comment: @Bruce If you're asking if *only* limiting the branch access on the server-side will solve your issue, then the answer is no, because in cloning the `feature/partner` branch they will have access to the full history; see the first part of my answer.

Comment: If I created an orphan branch and set the permission in Gitolite to `RW+ feature/orphan = @partners` and deny access to all other branches for @partners. Can @partners still access to the full history by doing the git clone the repository?

Comment: If no, it is because of the orphan branch doesn't have any ref point to any parent branch as your answer described, right? If yes, is it mean that I still have to move out the orphan branch to another repository for avoiding the reveal of the proprietary code?

Comment: No they can't access the full history if they only have access to the orphan branch. Correct, the commits in the orphan branch don't point to any of the private commits in the rest of your repo.