Same GitLab for multiple users with different content visibility
I am currently working on a project with multiple partners with the code stored in GitLab. Although the partners share the same core code, some files (for instance, preprocessing scripts for their own data) should only be seen by the partner who owns the respective data.
Initially, I thought about making a separate repo for all of them, but this results in a great overhead of updating all repos whenever I make a change to the core code.
What is the best way to share the main code considering that:

The users only see the core code and their respective code.
Whenever I make changes to the core code, they all get the updates.

Thanks

Cannot be done https://superuser.com/a/559978/259670

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348071/how-to-allow-per-user-protected-branches-access-in-gitlab , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41551001/can-we-set-the-permission-of-accessible-to-a-branch-only-in-a-git-repository Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+protect+user+access+branch

A repository is either accessible or not, it's impossible to hide a part of it. Splitting into multiple repos is the only solution.

Would you be willing to substitute: "should only be seen by..." with: "should only be edited by..."? If yes, GitLab can do that in a single repo. If no, you'll need multiple repos.

I only want them to see specific parts. Thank you for your answers. I will do multiple repos.


Initially, I thought about making a separate repo for all of them

Separate repositories remain the safest option in your case.

but this results in a great overhead of updating all repos whenever I make a change to the core code.

It should not, if each partners' repositories reference your own as a submodule, following a branch.
Then a git submodule update --remote should be enough to update said submodule to the latest of that branch.
